# Copy only some portion of values from a Two dimentional array

Tags: c#, .net, multidimensional-array

How can i copy only a small portion of two dimensional array to another two dimensional array

```
int[,] a = new int[3, 4] { { 1, 2, 3, 4 }, { 5, 6, 7, 8 }, { 9, 10, 11, 12 } };
int[,] b = new int[3, 2];
```

I want array `b` to hold values like `{ {  2, 3 }, { 6, 7 }, { 10, 11 } }`

Thanks

Comment: And what seems to be the problem?

Comment: Your pattern is taking second and third element right? Did you try _anything_ so far by the way?

Comment: Array copy is just copying everything.. I need only certain array positions to be copied

Answer (score 1):

There you go:

```
var b = a.Select(_ => _.Skip(1).Take(2).ToArray()).ToArray();
```